# How to get the number of weeks and its respective dates between two given dates (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, date

I'm new to VB.net and here's the example of what I'm looking for: `Date1 = 2/7/15` and `Date2 = 3/7/15`. The number of weeks between those two dates would be 4 and the resulting dates would be `2/14/15`, `2/21/15`, and so on. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Calendar.GetWeekOfYear()`

Comment: take a look at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: yes thank you. :) I could now get the # of weeks, but how could I get all the dates out of it?

Comment: When you say all the dates, do you mean all the days in between the two dates?

Comment: nope, just the dates of the weeks Ma'am/Sir. @CheGueVerra

Comment: Update your question with your expected results, every dates is still vague for me, my female side and male side don't agree on what you want

Comment: Just make a loop jumping by 7 each time (the size of the loop should probably be the number of weeks times 7). Then, print the dates or whatever you need..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **guess** based on what I **think** you want

```
Dim d1 As DateTime = #2/7/2015#
Dim d2 As DateTime = #3/7/2015#

Do While d1 < d2
    d1 = d1.AddDays(7)
    Debug.WriteLine(d1.ToShortDateString)
Loop
```

Comment: I modified it a bit. The AddDays() really helped. Thanks!